# setting IDocumentStore as a static variable in RavenDB .net

Tags: asp.net-core, static-methods, xunit, ravendb

I have a class that inherits RavenTestDriver.
I need to initialize the IDocumentStore just for the first time . Because for some reason I need just one object of this class .
So here is my code :

```
   public sealed class mystatic : RavenTestDriver
    {


        public static IDocumentStore store;
        // here something like this store= GetDocumentStore()
        public static IHostBuilder host = easy.api.Program.CreateHostBuilder(new string[0])
        .ConfigureWebHost(webHostBuilder =>
        {
            webHostBuilder.UseTestServer();
        }).ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
        {
            //config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
        })
       .ConfigureServices(services =>
       {
           services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserService, InitRequest>();
           services.AddScoped<ICacheStorage>(provider =>
           {
               return new Mock<ICacheStorage>().Object;
           });
           services.AddTransient<IAsyncDocumentSession>((c) =>
           {
               return store.OpenAsyncSession();
           });

       });
        public static IHost cli = host.Start();
    }
```

My question is how can I initialize the store variable ??
Or How can I initialize the store with GetDocumentStore() in static class?

Comment: I found this :https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.0/csharp/client-api/creating-document-store but  it returns Document store URLs cannot be empty (Parameter 'Urls')

Comment: As a note the above link is for ravendb client .but i need to create session from raventestdriver

Comment: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.3/csharp/start/test-driver

Comment: @Danielle Thanks but your link is not for static classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public class DocumentStoreHolder : RavenTestDriver
    {
        private IDocumentStore _store;

        public IDocumentStore Store => _store;

        public  DocumentStoreHolder()
        {
            _store = GetDocumentStore();
        }
    }

    public sealed class mystatic 
    {

        public static readonly IDocumentStore _store;

        static mystatic()
        {
            var storeHolder = new DocumentStoreHolder();
            _store = storeHolder.Store;

        }
}
```